# Как найти сумму двумерного массива?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть обобщенный метод в котором параметр принимает двумерный массив.
Вопрос, как найти сумму?
Код моих попыток ниже:

```java
static <T extends Number> T function(T array[][]) {
    Integer summ;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            summ = summ + array[i][j]; // error
        }
    }
    return summ; // error
}
```

Comment: Должно быть `for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){`

Comment: И нужно задать начальное значение summ = 0

Comment: автор, ваша задача не имеет решения!

Comment: @Санаев, почему?

Comment: @KonstantinVoskov единственное решение вашей задачи - это перегрузка методов! Не типичная задача для дженериков. Так как summ может быть и Float, и Integer, и Double.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать перегрузку. Это единственное верное решение вашей задачи! Так как summ может быть и Float, и Double, и Integer. То есть мы не можем явно проинициализировать значение этой переменной

```java
static Long function(Long array[][]) {
    Long summ = 0L;

    for (Long[] anArray : array) {
        summ += Stream
                .of(anArray)
                .mapToLong(s -> s)
                .sum();
    }
    return summ;
}
```

```java
static Double function(Double array[][]) {
    Double summ = 0.0;

    for (Double[] anArray : array) {
        summ += Stream
                .of(anArray)
                .mapToDouble(s -> s)
                .sum();
    }
    return summ;
}
```

```java
static Integer function(Integer array[][]) {
    Integer summ = 0;

    for (Integer[] anArray : array) {
        summ += Stream
                .of(anArray)
                .mapToInt(s -> s)
                .sum();
    }
    return summ;
}
```

Пример:

```java
Integer[][] s = new Integer[][]{{1, 4, 5}, {2, 2, 9}};
System.out.println(function(s));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```java
Double[][] s = new Double[][]{{1.4, 4.8, 5.9}, {2.4, 2.9, 9.3}};
System.out.println(function(s));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да походу. Скорее всего с javой не дружат

Answer (score 1):

**Обновление**

Принятый ответ мне не нравится из-за необходимости дублировать код. Есть и такой вариант через наследование. Преимущество в том, что если понадобится написать generic для других операций, либо добавить метод, который, например, считает сумму трёх чисел - не нужно будет опять писать переопределения, можно будет переиспользовать уже написанные калькуляторы. Похожий подход используется для `IComparer`

```
public abstract class Calculator<T>
{
    public abstract T Add(T a, T b);
    public abstract T DefaultValue();
}


public class IntegerCalculator extends Calculator<Integer>
{
    @Override 
    public Integer Add(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer DefaultValue() {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Integer nums[] = { 1,2,3 };
        System.out.println(summArr(nums, new IntegerCalculator()));
     }

     public static <T> T summArr(T[] numbers, Calculator<T> calc) {
        T summ = calc.DefaultValue();
        for(T num: numbers) {
            summ = calc.Add(num, summ);
        }
        return summ;
     }
}
```

**Оригинальный ответ**

1. Integer summ - объявляет переменную, но не задаёт ей значение. Чему равно summ + 5 ? Никто не знает, т.к. для summ не было задано начальное значение. Возможно в Java по умолчанию, это ноль, но лучше написать самому.
2. Двумерный массив - это массив массивов.

   Integer arr1[] - arr1[0] - это число, равное 1
   arr1: [1,2,3,4]

   Integer arr2[][] - arr2[0] - это массив, который состоит из чисел [1,2,3,4].
   arr2: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]].

Таким образом в коде две ошибки: не проиницилизорованно начальное значение summ и во-втором цикле используется arr.length, тогда, как нам нужна длина вложенного массива arr[i].length.

```
static <T extends Number> T function (T array[][]){
        T summ = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
                summ = summ + array[i][j]; // error
            }
        }
        return summ; // error
    }
```

Comment: Ошибка осталась

Comment: @KonstantinVoskov обновил, также в ответе ниже дали дельный совет сделать переменную summ типа T.

Comment: Неверно!!! мы не знаем вещественное ли значение у T или нет! мы не можем присвоить ее к нулю!!! только к null

Comment: @Санаев действительно, обновил ответ с альтернативой переопределению

Comment: @Nikita вот теперь мне ваш ответ понравился

Answer (score 0):

Обобщённый метод поможет из двухмерного массива сделать одномерный. Далее для каждого типа массива: `Integer[][]`, `Long[][]`, `Double[][]` - делаем перегрузку метода, суммирующего его элементы:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[][] arr1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    Long[][] arr2 = {{1L, 2L}, {3L, 4L}};
    Double[][] arr3 = {{1.1, 2.2}, {3.3, 4.4}};

    System.out.println(summingArray(arr1)); // 10
    System.out.println(summingArray(arr2)); // 10
    System.out.println(summingArray(arr3)); // 11.0
}

static int summingArray(Integer[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(flattenArray(arr, Integer[]::new))
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
}

static long summingArray(Long[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(flattenArray(arr, Long[]::new))
            .mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();
}

static double summingArray(Double[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(flattenArray(arr, Double[]::new))
            .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
}

static <T extends Number> T[] flattenArray(T[][] arr, IntFunction<T[]> function) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(function);
}
```